# Mathematica Remote Kernel On Windows

Tags: java, wolfram-mathematica

I want to configure a remote kernel of `Wolfram Mathematica` on a `Windows 8` and connect to that Kernel from another windows machine using `Java`. Is it necessary to have `Mathematica` installed on both machines and if not, how  can I connect to the Kernel through `Java`?